# Date Picker right below on click of custom edit text in a small popup window

Tags: android, android-layout

I have two custom edit texts.I want to open date picker on click of one of them.I want to implement a custom date picker which opens in a small popup box kind of a thing, right below my edit text with an arrow on side.and if I click on other one then a list view should appear,and current date picker must disappear. If I open it programatically, it covers the whole screen,and also I cannot click on edit text.So I did it in my xml code.But it is still not showing as per requirement.So what changes do I need to make so that it opens right below the edit text with small dialog box like structure.. If not then is there some library which can make this possible
Here is my xml code 
 for main activity xml

```
    <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context="com.example.root.customdatepicker.MainActivity">
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:orientation="horizontal"

    android:layout_height="match_parent">
    <EditText
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:id="@+id/listviewPickerEditText"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:focusable="false"
        android:layout_margin="5dp"
        android:background="@drawable/custom_edit_text"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
    <EditText
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:id="@+id/datePickerEditText"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:focusable="false"
        android:layout_margin="5dp"
        android:background="@drawable/custom_edit_text"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
</LinearLayout>
       <!-- <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="0.8"
            android:layout_height="0dp">


        </LinearLayout>-->
    </LinearLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Layout for popup window.

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">
    <DatePicker
        android:id="@+id/datePicker"
android:scrollY="4dp"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:endYear="2100"
        android:startYear="1900" >
    </DatePicker>
</LinearLayout>
```

And my main activity

```
 package com.example.root.customdatepicker;

import android.app.DatePickerDialog;
import android.content.Context;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBar;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Gravity;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.DatePicker;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.PopupWindow;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener {
EditText listViewPicker;
EditText datePickerEditText;
   DatePicker datePicker;
    LayoutInflater inflater;
    View popUpView;
    PopupWindow popupWindow;
    public boolean setEditFocus=true;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        listViewPicker = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.listviewPickerEditText);
        datePickerEditText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.datePickerEditText);

        inflater = (LayoutInflater) MainActivity.this.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        popUpView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.custom_popup_window, null, false);
        popupWindow=new PopupWindow(popUpView,
                700, 580,
                true);
        datePicker = (DatePicker) popUpView.findViewById(R.id.datePicker);
        popupWindow .setTouchable(true);
        popupWindow .setFocusable(true);
       // final DatePickerDialog dialog =  new DatePickerDialog(MainActivity.this, this, 2013, 2, 18);
//DatePickerDialog datePic = new DatePickerDialog()
       /* DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener date = new DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener() {

            @Override
            public void onDateSet(DatePicker view, int year, int monthOfYear,
                                  int dayOfMonth) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                Calendar myCalendar = Calendar.getInstance();
                myCalendar.set(Calendar.YEAR, year);
                myCalendar.set(Calendar.MONTH, monthOfYear);
                myCalendar.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, dayOfMonth);
                //updateLabel();
            }

        };*/
        listViewPicker.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
              //  Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"list picker",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
        });

        datePickerEditText.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
               // Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"date picker",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                int[] location = new int[2];
                datePickerEditText.getLocationOnScreen(location);
                popupWindow.showAtLocation(popUpView, Gravity.CENTER, location[0]-2, location[1]-2);
                /*if(datePicker!=null ) {
                    if(datePicker.isShown()) {
                        datePicker.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        datePicker.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                    }
                }*/

            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    public void onDateSet(DatePicker view, int year, int monthOfYear, int dayOfMonth) {

    }

    public void showPopup(int x,int y)
    {

    }
}
```

Thank you.
Also pls tell me if popup is correct option for this,if not then what else can be used.